# Text mining with tm - replaces document names with numbers

Tags: r, text-mining, tm

I'm trying to do text mining on various html files. I want the user to be able to type in any word and a list of all the documents that contain that word. The problem now is that my tdm has replaced all the document names with numbers. How can i fix this? Here's my code and results.

`library(tm)`
`corpus <- Corpus(
  DirSource("~/shiny-dashboard/New_Shiny/site_dumps/", encoding = "UTF-8"),readerControl = list(language = "en")
)`
`corpus <- sapply(corpus, function(x) iconv(x, "latin1", "ASCII", sub=""))`
`corpus <- Corpus(VectorSource(corpus),encoding = "UTF-8", readerControl = list(language = "en"))`
`corpus<-tm_map(corpus, removeNumbers)`
`corpus<-tm_map(corpus, removePunctuation)`
`corpus<- tm_map(corpus,content_transformer(tolower))`
`corpus <-tm_map(corpus, removeWords,stopwords("english"))`
`corpus <-tm_map(corpus, stripWhitespace)`
`corpus <-tm_map(corpus, stemDocument)`
`tdm = DocumentTermMatrix(corpus)`
`as.data.frame(inspect(tdm[,"love"]))`

this is the output.

`Terms
Docs   class   div  font  href  http onion span style  text title
  119     47 17198    28  4290  4430 11016    7    35    23     5
  138      3     6 21874 10937 21900 22101    0 21877 32819     3
  205   1169   604    26  2212  1067     6 1167   218    83   771
  241 133156 89668     4 15921    11    13  688  6785    24 44826
  248    265   230    79   112   136    94   24    29    90    38
  260      1     0   478  1938   577    10    0    91    44     2
  376   2480    20     4  1022   577     0 2808     6   372   829
  449   8230 13168  9880  2097   737   665    0  3299     2     2
  474    466   481   133    57    49    18  333   523   183   119
  50   12883 17179    30  5572  5728 11964  192   167    75    11`

Comment: Please provide a small, representative sample of the data in a way that makes it possible for us to reproduce this entire example on our machines. When building the corpus on the second line, we do not have access to your local directory to get the data. Thanks :)

Comment: It is folder containing html files(web pages). It has over 5000 html files. I'm not sure how i can share those.

Comment: All these html files have different names, which i why i need the document names so i can see which document contains what